# Differentiating an integral that contains dy/du w.r.t x

Tags: calculus

[image: QUESTION]

I have to differentiate both sides of this equation by dx, I have seen the answer but I still don't understand it, can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous and $F(x)=\int_0^x f(u) du$, then $F$ is differentiable and $F'=f$.

(FTC)